# Indentation does not work when using gtsummary package to publish table to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary, flextable, gt

I'm trying to publish a table in a pdf format using the gtsummary package in Rmarkdown. The code in Rmarkdown is as below:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
summary(mod)

```

```{r message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
```
    
```{r}
tbl_regression(mod, intercept = TRUE)
```
````

I tried using `as_gt()` after the `tbl_regression` function but got an error when knitting. I also tried using `as_flextable()`, but the indentation still doesn't work. Is there any way to publish a table using `tbl_regression()` in pdf format and keep the indentation of categorical variables?

Is there an additional function in gtsummary that I need to use? Alternatively, I would prefer to use either gt or flextable packages in addition if needed, but I'm open to other solutions as well. Thanks!

Comment: I can't say for 'gt' but the implemtation for 'flextable' does not contain any tabulation `\t` (I think the padding is used which exclude PDF as a valid output)

Answer (score 1):

One option to keep the indentation would be to use `as_kable_extra`.

Note: To get the same look as the default printing via `knitr::kable` requires to add some additional arguments.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
```

```{r message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
```
    
```{r}
tbl_regression(mod, intercept = TRUE)
```
    
```{r}
tbl_regression(mod, intercept = TRUE) |> 
  as_kable_extra(booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "") |> 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
    position = "center",
    latex_options = "hold_position"
  )
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This keeps the indentation for the categorical variables in the table! Do you know how I can keep the superscript in the footnote? It looks like that disappeared in the table.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your example code, a large message is printed:

```
## Table printed with `knitr::kable()`, not {gt}. Learn why at
## https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html
## To suppress this message, include `message = FALSE` in code chunk header.
```

If you go to the referenced link, you'll see that kable does not fully support all styling elements, including indentation.

Use huxtable to print the gtsummary table if you're output type is pdf:

```r
tbl_regression(mod, intercept = TRUE) |> 
  as_hux_table()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This keeps the indentation! But I notice that the footnotes' superscripts disappear using this option. Are there additional options to keep superscripts using the Huxtable package?